# angular.bootstrap and angular ui-router not launching controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, angular-ui-router

I'm in the process of switching an existing AngularJS mobile app from [Trigger.io](https://trigger.io/) to Cordova, as it provides way better/more plugins for what I'm building.

Cordova requires my application to be loaded after the [`deviceready` event](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready) is fired. My application is built on top of the ionic framework, and they provide a wrapper (`window.ionic.Platform.ready`) for this event. I thought it was going to be as simple as removing `ng-app` from my HTML and bootstrap my app when the device is ready. Alas...

I came across something weird. I'm using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) to handle my states and they get triggered in the `$stateChangeStart`, but the controller linked to that state does not get triggered at all.

I've made two Plunkrs as example;

- the [first one](http://plnkr.co/edit/IT5YdcdROB22TA5ak7vo?p=preview) uses `ng-app` and works perfectly
- the [second one](http://plnkr.co/edit/O3cjya0riunUTFF9irWq?p=preview) uses `angular.bootstrap`, but never `console.log`s stuff from my controllers.

Am I doing something wrong here? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is with the selection of rootElement, you need to just get the body via `document.body` instead you are trying to retrieve it as `document.getElementById('body')` which does not return anything.

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['myApp']);
});
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/sgcE2i?p=preview)**

Comment: Holy crap, you have no idea how much time I wasted today trying to fix this. Thanks a lot, going to accept this in a few minutes :-)..

Comment: @Nick whenever you are back, please do remember to accept. Thx!!

Comment: Sorry, you answered so quickly I couldn't hit accept just yet and forgot about it, did it now! Thanks again!