# routeProvider is not executed consistently after using cordova plugins

Tags: angularjs, cordova

This is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
    or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
    distributed with this work for additional information
    regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
    to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
    "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
    with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
    software distributed under the License is distributed on an
    "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
     KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
    specific language governing permissions and limitations
    under the License.
-->
<html ng-app='pod'>
    <head>
        <!--
        Customize this policy to fit your own app's needs. For more guidance, see:
            https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/blob/master/README.md#content-security-policy
        Some notes:
            * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
            * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
            * Disables use of inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
                * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
        -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
       <!--  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css"

       > -->
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/test.css">
          <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular-route.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/router.js"></script>  
         <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/common/service.js"></script> --> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller/LoginController.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller/ScanMilkRunController.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller/DealersListController.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller/ScanDeliveryParcelController.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/common/service.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<!--
        <div class="app">
             MAIN CONTENT AND INJECTED VIEWS 
            <div id="main">
-->         <div class = "login">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                      <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-8">
                        <img src="img/logo.jpg" class="img-logo">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-4">
                        <div class="login-header">
                          <h1 style="font-size:32px">CAT Group <br>Driver<br>Deliveries</h1>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
               </div> 
                <div ng-view></div>
<!--
            </div>
        </div>
-->

    </body>
</html>
```

THis is my routeProvider:

```
angular.module('pod', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function($routeProvider) {
    // URL Routing Configuration
    alert('route');
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'templates/Login.html',
            controller : 'LoginController'
        })
        .when('/dealersList', {
            templateUrl : 'templates/DealersList.html',
            controller : 'DealersListController'
        })
});
```

this is my login.html

```
 <div class = "login">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="login-form">
          <h4>Driver Name</h4>
          <input type="text" ng-model="driverName" ng-bind="driverName"  placeholder="Driver Name">
           <h4>Password</h4>
          <input type="Password" ng-model="password" placeholder="Password">
          <!--       <input type="button" value="Reset" ng-click = "reset()"/>-->
          <div class="remember_me">
           <input type="checkbox" ng-model="chk" value="Remember Me">Remember Me</br>
         </div>
         <input type="button" value = "Login" ng-click = "Login()"/>
         <input type="button"  value = "Reset" ng-click = "reset()"/>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

this is my loginController:

```
var app = angular.module('pod');
app.controller('LoginController', function($scope, $location, podService) {
    $scope.reset = function() {
       $scope.driverName = '';
       $scope.password = '';
    };
    $scope.Login = function(){
       if($scope.driverName == "" || $scope.driverName == null){
           //alert("Cie Name is required");
           navigator.notification.alert("Driver Name is required", loginAlertCallback, 'Alert', 'Ok');
       }
       else if($scope.password == "" || $scope.password == null){
           navigator.notification.alert("Password is required", loginAlertCallback, 'Alert', 'Ok');
       }else{
        podService.setDriverName($scope.driverName);
            $location.path('/scanMilkRun');
                cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
            function (result) {
                $scope.milkRunCode = result.text;
                gatheringData();
            }, 
            function (error) {
                alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
            }
        );
        }
    };
    function gatheringData(){
        //          cordova.plugin.pDialog.init({progressStyle : 'HORIZONTAL', title: '', message : 'Gathering Data...'});
        //         cordova.plugin.pDialog.setProgress(90);   
        //          cordova.plugin.pDialog.setCancelable(false); 
        //          cordova.plugin.pDialog.dismiss();   
        // navigateDealersList();
         $location.path('/dealersList');

    }
    function navigateDealersList(){
        alert('4');


    }
});
```

So while clicking the login button i will call an barcodescanner using an plugin in cordova and in barcode success function i am trying to navigate to another form "dealerslist" using "$location.path('/dealersList')" but it is not navigating the dealerspage.

So kindly help me to fix the issue

Comment: Do you have any (javascript) errors in your console?

Comment: No i didn't see any javascript errors in console

Comment: Some one help me to resolve this issue... I am trying to resolve it from morning but no luck..

Comment: Before invoking `gatheringData` there is already a `$location.path('/scanMilkRun');` This path does not occur in your `routeProvider`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular.bootstrap and angular ui-router not launching controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28054649/angular-bootstrap-and-angular-ui-router-not-launching-controllers)